# Unable to wrap functions assigned with events parameter in backbone model

Tags: backbone.js, model

Motivation: I want to wrap all functions within backbone model with log functionality to make it more easy to follow function calls.

I am iterating over models functions and warping them with underscores wrap().

But it looks like event function bindings from 'events' hash doesn't get wrapped as it looks like these functions are copied and stored somewhere in DOM, not sure.

Has anybody came to this problem as well or any ideas how to workaround?

Manually entering console.log() in these function is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're experiencing the same problem as when people are trying to test the functionality provided with the `events` -hash. Spying on the event callback directly on the View doesn't work, but spying on the class prototype before instantiating works.

```
// This won't work
var view =  new SomeView();
spyOn(view, 'onClick');
view.$el.click(); // spy isn't called

// This works
spyOn(SomeView.prototype, 'onClick');
var view =  new SomeView();
view.$el.click(); // spy is called
```

Try iterating over the `prototype` of your 'class' right after creating it, because that should be where the methods called by the `events` -implementation should reside.

Comment: Nice idea, will try when will have time to come back to this problem. But looks like this should do the trick.